# PHP Convert String formatted like an array to array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a string like this :

[ 2 => ["Iphone 10", "Iphone 20", "Iphone 30", "Iphone 40"], 3 => ["Mac 10", "Mac 20", "Mac 30", "Mac 40"] ]

I would like to transform it an array . i try to cast it (with (array) in front), but doesn't work. What would be the best way ?

Comment: I think this is an array, not a string.

Comment: Could you please put exact string here?

Comment: @MuhammadHassanJaved i edited my post. This is my string

Comment: how do you get this string?

Answer (score 0):

I think the way i get this string is wrong.
I decide to edit it, and get a json format in replacement. It's easier to manage then.

Comment: Better to post the solution here.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if it's best way but this gives solution to your problem.
Here's online example: https://onlinephp.io/c/96a069f5-f11f-4546-86ff-f99ebb3c5800

```
$string = '[ 2 => ["Iphone 10", "Iphone 20", "Iphone 30", "Iphone 40"], 3 => ["Mac 10", "Mac 20", "Mac 30", "Mac 40"] ]';
$array = explode('"', $string);
$iphones = array_filter($array, function($item) {
    $index = strpos($item, "I");
    if($index !== false) return true;
    return false;
});
$macs = array_filter($array, function($item) {
    $index = strpos($item, "M");
    if($index !== false) return true;
    return false;
});

$outputArray = [1, $iphones, $macs];

unset($outputArray[0]);

var_dump($outputArray);
```

Comment: This is very questionable. It does not really implement what the OP asked for: to convert a string containing some array notation into an array. This assumes knowledge about the structure and semantics of the content of that data. So it is a very specialized solution. Which will fail the moment the data contains other values than shown in the example in the question.